# Uninstall yeoman office js addin in mac

Tags: office-js, yeoman

I have an office js addin that is side loaded while I am developing. I have tried to use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache to remove this in my mac but I cannot get it to not show up in the addins menu. What i would like to know is

1.) How do I get rid of the existing addins
2.) How do I create an addin that allows you to uninstall it automatically

Thanks in advance.

I tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache and it is not removing the test addins that I sideloaded during development.

[Excel Addins that I want to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8s6.png)

I am new so I am not allowed to embed pictures the link StackOverflow gave is here I wanted to get rid of these 2 but cant find where they are to delete them!

Comment: What Office application are you extending? Word? Excel? ... ?

Comment: I am extending Office Excel

Comment: Try removing the manifest from:
`/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef` If that works, I'll make it the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the manifest from: /Users//Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef